# lightbox with 2 different progress bar inside

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a lightbox in javascript and I have placed inside it a progress bar that I have also created it in javascript. My problem is that when I was trying to insert a second progress bar inside my lightbox only the first works. Any idea how to fix this?

this is my jsfiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/QHMKk/3/

and my code is this:

my javascript is:

```
function show() {
document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
}

function start() {
var stepSize = 50;
setTimeout((function() {
var filler = document.getElementById("filler"),
percentage = 0;
return function progress() {
  filler.style.height = percentage + "%";
  percentage +=1;
  if (percentage <= 100) {
    setTimeout(progress, stepSize);
 }
}

}()), stepSize);
}


function start() {
var stepSize = 50;
setTimeout((function() {
var filler2 = document.getElementById("filler2"),
percentage = 0;
return function progress() {
  filler.style.height = percentage + "%";
  percentage +=1;
  if (percentage <= 100) {
    setTimeout(progress, stepSize);
 }
}

}()), stepSize);
}
```

this is my html:

```
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "show(); start();"> OPEN</a>

  <div id="light" class="white_content_stats">

  <div class="prog">
    <div id="filler" class="filler"></div>
  </div>
  </br> 
  <div class="prog2">
    <div id="filler2" class="filler2"></div>
  </div>


<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = " document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'; "> 
</br>CLOSE</a>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
  .black_overlay_stats{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        z-index:1001;
        -moz-opacity: 0.6;
        opacity:.70;
        filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    }
    .white_content_stats {
        display: none;
        position:fixed;
        top: 15%;
        width: 300px;

        padding: 30px;
        margin-left:10px;
        background-color:#F2F2F2;   

        border-radius: 0px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);    
        z-index:1002; 
    }



.prog {
    height: 100px;
    width: 30px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    position: relative;
}
.filler {
    height: 0%;
    width: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: grey;
}


.prog2 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 30px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    position: relative;
}
.filler2 {
    height: 0%;
    width: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: any idea why second progress bar under first one cannot start ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define 2 functions with the same name `start`, so the second will be used and only it will be run, hence you can see only 1 progress bar works. You can modify the function `start` to make it accept an argument of `id` like this:

```
function start(id) {
    //...
    var filler = document.getElementById(id)
    //...
}
```

Then call both `start('filler')` and `start('filler2')`:

```
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "show(); start('filler'); start('filler2');"> OPEN</a>
```

### [Updated Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/QHMKk/4/)

Note that you should not use **inline** event property.